Proof of Laurent Series Development
I'm currently reading a book about complex analysis. At this point in the book, the author introduces Laurent series and states that

Every function $f$ which is holomorphic on the ring $\{z \in \mathbb C: r < \left|z-z_0\right| < R\}$ can be expressed as a laurent series $\sum c_n(z-z_0)^n$.

In the proof, his main point is the following image,

where he argues that by the integral theorem of Cauchy, we can transform the circle-integral to the ring-integral. Why is this correct? The intuition is clear, but I cannot find a result which gives this in a rigorous way.
In terms of formula he writes: $$\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\left|{\zeta-z} \right| = \varepsilon} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} \mathrm d\zeta \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\left|\zeta\right| = R-\delta}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} \mathrm d\zeta + \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\left|\zeta\right| = r+\delta}\frac{f(\zeta)}{-(\zeta - z)} \mathrm d\zeta.
\end{align}$$
The $-$ in the denominator of the fraction in the second integral is a result of switching the direction of the curve.

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2033127/42969

If you consider the ring with the little disk removed, the function $\zeta\longmapsto f(\zeta)/(\zeta-z)$ is analytic, so Cauchy Theorem tells you that the integral is zero. The boundary of this region is $\{|\zeta|=R+\delta\}-\{\|\zeta|=R-\delta\}-\{|\zeta-z|=\varepsilon\}$. Thus
$$
0= \int\limits_{\left|\zeta\right| = R-\delta}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} \mathrm d\zeta - \int\limits_{\left|\zeta\right| = R+\delta}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} \mathrm d\zeta-\int\limits_{\left|{\zeta-z} \right|= \varepsilon} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} \mathrm d\zeta.
$$
